# Why i cant add an image src attribute in fetch .then?

Tags: javascript, image, attributes, fetch, src

```
dropdown.addEventListener('change', event => {
fetch(`https://dog.ceo/api/breed/${dropdown.value}/images/random`)
    .then(response => {
        if (response.ok) {
            return response.json()
        }
        throw new Error('Bad HTTP')
    })
    .then(jsonData => {
        let image = document.createElement('image')
        let src = jsonData.message
        image.src = src;
        image.className = 'newClass'
        console.log(src)
        console.log(image)
        result.appendChild(image)
    })
```

})

[console.log image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4Uvr.png)

the image is my consol.logs, class is added well, but src is failed, could someone explain what am i doing wrong:(?

Comment: have you tried `image.setAttribute('src',src)` instead of `image.src = src`?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is creating `"image"` instead of `"img"`.`image` tag will create [: The obsolete Image element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/image) not the [`<img>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img)

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/image)

> Creating an  element without a `src` attribute results in an `HTMLElement` object with the local element name `"image"`

`HTMLElement` doesnot have any `src` property so the `src` as attribute is not set

#### Incorrect

```js
let image = document.createElement('image')
image.src ="something"

console.log(image.outerHTML)
```

When you create `document.createElement('image')` this will not create the ImageElement

#### Correct

```js
let image = document.createElement('img')
image.src ="something"

console.log(image.outerHTML)
```

Comment: "The obsolete HTML Image element (<image>) is an obsolete remnant of an ancient version of HTML lost in the mists of time; use the standard <img> element instead." - MDN